# Clustering non-matrix string arrays

Tags: c#, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, accord.net

I'm looking for a way to implement a cluster algorithm that should be able to clusterize string arrays.

Assuming inputs like those:

```
string[][] input =
{
     new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "F", "G"},
     new string[] { "D", "F", "G", "H"},
     new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "G"},
     new string[] { "B", "C", "Z", "A", "F"},
     new string[] { "O", "N", "P", "X"}
};
```

The algorithm should be able to identify that item 0, 2 and 3 are at the same cluster. But how can i do this?

***What I've tried?***
I've been trying to use Accord.net framework to build a KMeans cluster. But I noticed that Kmeans only work with double numbers (so I converter each value in the string[] to a number an tried again). 
As distance meansurement I implemented [Jaccard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) distance.

After this I'm getting an error that says that "The points matrix should be rectangular." That makes sense because my inputs are not a rectangular matrix.

So I ask you guys: How could I implement this? Whats the best approach to cluster items in such situation? Any thoughts or suggestions?

Code sample:

```
double[][] inputs =
{
     new double [] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 },
     new double [] { 0, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4 },
     new double [] { 33, 0, 1, 5, 2, 4 },
     new double [] { 0, 1, 2, 6, 7,  8},
     new double [] { 0, 9, 1, 2, 6, 8 },
     new double [] { 0, 4, 10, 15, 11, 12, 13  },
     new double [] { 0, 4, 14, 15, 11, 12, 13, 16  },
     new double [] { 0, 17, 18, 11, 19, 12, 20},
     new double [] { 0, 17, 18, 11, 19, 12, 20, 15, 26},
     new double [] { 0, 4, 14, 15, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18  },
     new double [] { 0, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 25},
     new double [] { 24, 26, 27, 21, 28, 29, 1},
     new double [] { 24, 243, 26, 30},
     new double [] { 31, 24, 22, 23, 0, 11, 26 }
     // Many others... 
};

var kmeans   = new KMeans(k: 3, distance: new JaccarDistanceDouble() );
var clusters = kmeans.Learn(inputs); // Throws the error.
int[] labels = clusters.Decide(inputs);
```

Comment: I never worked with these algorithms, but I think that the input of the clustering algorithm should be the matrix of the Jaccard distances. And the latter would be rectangular and of type double.

Comment: I'll do some tests, but I think Its not going to work because the KMeans needs to compute the distance from element[0] with each other element so he can compute the K nearest itens to form a cluster.  But I will try your suggestion. Thanks @OlivierJacot-Descombes

Comment: Or treat the input as 1-dimensional problem, where the input is a an array of sets of letters. Each set of letters would be treated a single object whose distance to others has to be determined. Now, the input to the clustering algorithm is a vector instead of a matrix.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: no, k-means needs coordinates, not distances. It only makes sense to be used with continuous variables.

Answer (score 1):

K-means **requires** continuous variables.

Because it needs to compute the **mean**. Hence the name.

Therefore, you cannot use k-means on this data.

Rather, choose other clustering algorithms. But I doubt that clustering is going to solve your problem (but you didn't explain your problem). More likely, something else such as frequent itemset mining will be the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `k-means` should not be used for clustering categorical data is because, the sample space for categorical data is discrete, and doesn't have a natural origin. A Euclidean distance function on such a space isn't really meaningful.

Since you are dealing with string or categorical data, try `k-modes` algorithm can be applied. Althiugh there exists several other algorithms too for categorical data clustering K-mode is an extension of the classical k-means. For a detailed discussion you can read this [paper](http://www.cs.ust.hk/~qyang/Teaching/537/Papers/huang98extensions.pdf). I do not know how it can be implemented in `C#` but for `R` you can see this [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/klaR/versions/0.6-14/topics/kmodes).

Besides, you can also do `one-hot encoding` which is a representation of categorical variables as binary vectors and then apply k-means. But then you might run the risk of the *curse of dimensionality*.

Answer (score -1):

You might sort each one-dimensional array individually and then fill them with 0's for missing values. At that point you can apply the `jaccard` or `cosine` etc.